# Add to Cart Using Laravel Session

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel sessions to store cart information on the web browser but I am getting this error "Trying to get property of a non object" when am testing. Any insights? the first snippet is controller then my model.I am using two foreach to retrieve the product information then display them on a modal where a user can now add to cart.

```html
    public function addtoCart(Request $request, $id){
        $product = Product::find($id);

        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->$id);
        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        dd($request->session()->get('cart'));
        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Added Successfully');
    }
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Cart 
{

    public $items = null;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalprice = 0;

    public function _construct($oldCart){

        if ($oldCart) {
            $this->items = $oldCart->items;         
            $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;           
            $this->totalprice = $oldCart->totalprice;           
        }
    }

    public function add($item,$id){
        $storedItem = ['qty'=>0, 'price' =>$item->price, 'item' ->$item->item];

        if ($this->items) {
            if (array_key_exists($id,$this->items)) {
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem; 
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalprice += $item->price; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Product::find($id), the passed Id probably doesn't exists in your table. Make sure to pass  an actual record.

Comment: It does exist @Mick2160

Comment: Usually this error occurs when the record is not found. Maybe you are retrieving from the wrong table just double check. Hope it helps. @Chalo

Comment: i just did a dump and die just after the find method and it fetched the specific data of that id, that is not the issue

Comment: After some research I realized I have to json decode then encode for it too be presented as an object in my controller:
        $product = json_decode(json_encode($product));
Though in my model I am storing the data as an array                  
       $storedItem  = ['qty'=>0, 'price' =>$item->price, 'item' ->$item->product_name];   How can I convert it to a a string....   @Mick2160